# CodeIgniter - Links aren’t working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am developing a website in CodeIgniter. I’ve some unusual or weird issue with it. The links stopped working all of a sudden. We had stopped working on the site for couple of weeks. Yesterday we resumed working on it. But was surprised to see the links aren’t working. For safety purposes, what we do is we daily make a copy of the folder, so that in case any problem in the latest folder, we can go back to previous one. Suddenly the links aren’t working. What’s disappointing is even the links in the previous folders aren’t working. We didn’t touch the folders for more than two weeks. Nobody did any changes on the folder. The last time we worked on the site, links were fine. But now suddenly the links aren’t working. Very strange. Take a look at the attached photo. If we hover on the link, the url shows up at the bottom of the browser. But when we click on it, it doesn’t work. None of the links are working. If we inspect the element, the links/URLs are coming correctly from the database. But clicking isn’t working. Suddenly. I can’t post the any code here because i don’t know which one to post here, as the links in the entire site isn’t working. Any idea what might be the possible cause? Thanks.[image]

Comment: you mean the pages are broken or the links don't redirect the page? Like - what happens if you type that url in the browser manually? Do you get a js error? Maybe there's a generic event listener on a tags returning false.

Comment: @Kai Qing - Links don't get redirected to that page. Doesn't throw any error. Don't know what's happening.

Comment: Maybe there is no error. Like I said, maybe something is returning false when you click. Have you disabled js just to rule that out?

Comment: @Kai Qing - No we haven't disabled any js. We thought it might be some issue with the browser. We tested it in all the browsers. Links aren't working in any of them.

Comment: Yeah, so try disabling it and see if they work without js running.

Comment: When you click the link, does the page redirect? Does it redirect to the correct url? Can you break down how your URL structure works in relation to controller/method/variable and post the relevent code from your routes.php

Comment: @Kai Qing - We found out the issue. One of our guys had written a faulty javascript which was causing the issue. Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: I added an answer in case you wanted to accept something for this question. Alternatively you can delete the question. Either way you don't want an open question out there since it will hurt your reputation on the site and discourage people from helping in the future. Have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links in fact WERE being interrupted by a problem in javascript, as suggested in the first comment. In many cases, an anomalous functionality issue like this, which cannot be tied to code, can be identified fairly easily by turning js off. Here is a link to explain how to do it in each browser:

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/enabling-javascript.html

This question also demonstrates how many js related issues may not have an error to follow. If someone specifically coded a listener to return false for all a tags, it is not technically a bug, but more careless development since the listener is probably doing exactly what it is being told to do.

In your case, a spontaneous presence of an error like this could probably have been traced pretty easily through server logs - to see last modified uploaded files, or through the history of a repository like mercurial, git, or svn. Many repo interfaces will provide a comparison or detail explaining what was last changed. You may have been able to catch the problem with minimal effort that way.

Just a couple suggestions is all. Repos and js disabling has helped me many times to resolve random problems in group development environments.